# Highlight rows in Excel that contain every number from another row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet which has thousands of rows with 6 columns, each column has a number.

What I'm trying to do is highlight any rows with the numbers in it matching all the numbers from another row.

For example:

```
A1: 22, B1: 19, C1: 11, D1: 17, E1: 08, F1: 01
A2: 08, B2: 17, C2: 22, D2: 01, E2: 19, F2: 11
```

If these were the only rows I have, I would expect both of these rows to be highlighted since all the numbers in each of them match all the numbers in another row.

Can this be done?

Comment: If a row's numbers from A column to F column are exactly the same as the numbers from another row in the spreadsheet (In my example, that would be the second row), then highlight the entire row.

Comment: Not duplicated. If you look at my example above, those two rows aren't duplicates of each other, but they do contain the exact same numbers as each other, just in different columns. What I want is to mark any row that meets this criteria somehow. I thought highlighting would be the best way.

Comment: How do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Solution]

In my solution, I used a few helper columns.

The formula in Cell `G2` is

```
=SMALL($A2:$F2,COLUMN()-6)&";"
```

> Drag it across to Column L, and then drag it down to Row 8. The logic is to sort the numbers in Column A to F form smallest to largest, and add a special symbol semicolon `;` at the end of each value.

The formula in Cell `M2` is

```
=G2&H2&I2&J2&K2&L2
```

> Drag it down to Row 8. The logic is to combine the values into one string. If you have access to **TEXTJOIN** function, you can use this **array formula** `=TEXTJOIN(";",0,SMALL($A2:$F2,ROW($1:$6)))` without the need of creating the helper column G to L. As it is an array formula you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> upon finishing the formula in the formula bar.

The formula in Cell `N2` is

```
=COUNTIF($M$2:$M$8,M2)>1
```

> Dray it down to Row 8. The logic is to find out if the string has appeared more than once in the range, if so returns `TRUE`.

Lastly, highlight `A1:F8`, set up the conditional formatting rule using the following formula and choose the desired color for highlighting:

```
=$N2
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: It does exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: @acmarston happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume the data put in Column A to Column F, all are 2 digits text value

In A1:F1, enter : 22,19,11,17,08,01

In A2:F2, enter : 08,17,22,01,19,11

In helper, G1 formula copied down :

```
=TEXT(SUM(LARGE(--MID(A1&B1&C1&D1&E1&F1,{1,3,5,7,9,11},2),{1;2;3;4;5;6})*{1;100;10000;1000000;100000000;10000000000}),"000000000000")
```

Then, select A1:G2 >> Condition Formatting >> New rule >> choose, Use a formula…...>>

> > in the rule box enter :

```
=COUNTIF($G$1:$G$2,$G1)>1
```

> > Click Format >> choose cell background color
> >
> > OK >> Finish